# Define array Type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have initialized such string Array

```
var capitals = arrayOf("Tokyo","Moscow","Paris","Washington","Beijing")
```

But I have not specified its type to String. I thought when I use arrayOf constructor after the elements I should specify type.

[image]

Trying code below gives me errors property gettter and setter expected

Why I cannot have the type specified within `<>` brackets?

```
var capitals = arrayOf("Tokyo","Moscow","Paris","Washington","Beijing"):Array<String>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to specify type after variable declaration, not after initialization:

```kotlin
var capitals: Array<String> = arrayOf("Tokyo", "Moscow", "Paris", "Washington", "Beijing")
```

or you can explicitly set type parameter of `arrayOf`:

```kotlin
var capitals = arrayOf<String>("Tokyo", "Moscow", "Paris", "Washington", "Beijing")
```

Answer (score 2):

> I thought when I use arrayOf constructor after the elements I should specify type.

The compiler needs to know the type of every value — but it can often [infer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) the type from what it already knows.  So it's common¹ to omit the type.

In this case, the compiler knows that every element is a `String`, so the list type can only be `String` (or one of its supertypes: `String?`, `CharSequence`, `CharSequence?`, `Comparable<String>`, `Comparable<String>?`, `Any`, and `Any?`).  So it infers the most restrictive valid type: `List<String>`.

Of course, you can manually specify the type if you want to.  (You might want to be able to set nulls or other non-String values in the array later on, for example.)  In fact, in this case there are two ways you could do that.  You could specify the type parameter for `arrayOf()`:

```
var capitals = arrayOf<Any?>("Tokyo", "Moscow", "Paris", "Washington", "Beijing")
```

Or you could specify the type of the variable you're assigning it to²:

```
var capitals: Array<Any?> = arrayOf("Tokyo", "Moscow", "Paris", "Washington", "Beijing")
```

Both have the same effect here, though the first is probably better.  (It's shorter, which is always good!  Also, it extends to more complex expressions.)

---

<sup>1</sup>: There are a few cases where it's good practice to specify the type explicitly, even when you don't need to.  For example:

- You might want to deliberately loosen the type, as shown above.
- You might have a value returned from a Java function, where the compiler can't tell whether it should be nullable or not (a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)).  If you happen to know this, you can specify a nullable or non-nullable type accordingly.
- You might have a function which is part of your public API, and you don't want to risk its type changing indirectly as a result of some internal changes.  (This is only an issue for functions defined with an [expression body](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#single-expression-functions), of course; you always have to specify a type for a [block body](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#top) unless it's returning [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#unit-returning-functions).)

---

<sup>2</sup>: That second example shows that the compiler uses the surrounding context when inferring types.  If it looked *only* at the `String` parameters when inferring the type parameter for `arrayOf()`, then that would give an `Array<String>` — which can't be assigned to an `Array<Any?>` variable, because `Array` is not [covariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)!

But, as the [language spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#local-type-inference) says:

> the types of expressions may be derived not only from their arguments, but from their usage as well.

Answer (score 0):

And also you can `as` Keyword to specific your type by:

```
var capitals = arrayOf("Tokyo", "Moscow", "Paris", "Washington", "Beijing") as Array<String>
```

Comment: That only works here because you're casting to the same type.  If you cast to a different type, you'll get a runtime error (either an immediate `ClassCastException` or a later `ArrayStoreException`).  (Also, there's an extraneous `:`.)

Comment: that is! if you wanna use different types you should try `as Array<Any>` and this for all kotlin types

Comment: No, that won't work properly.  `as` is a cast, and a cast doesn't *convert* the value to the required type — it promises the compiler that it already *is* the correct type.  And in this case, it's not!  `Array` is not covariant in Kotlin (unlike Java), so `Array<Any>` and `Array<String>` are incompatible types.  Either the cast will give a runtime error, or attempts to use the array afterward may do so.

Comment: And what i mean in my first comment is `as Array<String>` and `arrayOf<String>` can gave you the same results Even they have different `Exception` Right?